# Woocommerce Subscriptions How to Remove Checkout Information

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I am building a membership website where one can become a member of paying a sign up fee for a limited time. So there is no monthly fee. I have set monthly fee as $0 / month in woocommerce subscriptions.

But the problem is that $0/ month for x months shows in checkout page which is just un-necessary information I just want to display signup fee and no monthly recurring amount.
[image]

What would be best way to do this?

Ahmar

Comment: You could probably either filter `woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string_inclusions` array or the full string via `woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string`. See the `get_price_string()` method in the `class-wc-subscriptions.php` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in functions.php:

```
function my_example_filter( $include, $product ) {

    $mynewarray = array(
                'tax_calculation'     => false,
                'subscription_price'  => true,
                'subscription_period' => true,
                'subscription_length' => false,
                'sign_up_fee'         => false,
                'trial_length'        => false
            );

    return $mynewarray;
}
```

This only leaves in the price and the period.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string_inclusions', 'my_example_filter', 10, 2);
```